# How do I reference jQuery from my HTML/JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined, referenceerror

I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error.
I assume everything is ok and working. My JQuery code is inside my Javascript file. I assume that isn't how it works? Should I have a JQuery file?

I have this inside the head of my HTML
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

This is my Javascript file:

```
function typing(id, sentence){
var result = $.Deferred();
    var index=0;
    var intObject= setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+=sentence[index]; 
        index++;
        if(index==sentence.length){
            clearInterval(intObject);
        }
    }, 100);
    return result.promise();
}

var sleep = function(ms) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(result.resolve, ms);
    return result.promise();
};

typing('container','Subject Name:').then(function() {
      return sleep(500);
    }).then(function() {
      return typing('container',' Hi')
    });
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: *"My JQuery is inside my Javascript, I assume that's how it works."* Huh?

Comment: Please post your html code, in order to see where you have added a reference to jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is fairly unclear, but essentially, you just have to make sure jQuery is loaded **before** your code. So for instance:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="your-code.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Your code
</script>
```

But **not**

```
<!-- Not like this -->
<script src="your-code.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note the order of tags.

These tags do not need to be in the `head`, and in fact, putting them there is [not best practice](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom). They must be in `head` or `body`. Best practice barring a specific reason to do something else is to put them at the very end of `body`, e.g.:

```
<!-- site content here -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="your-code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So much trouble for something so simple! Thank you very much, I totally missed out that one.
Will accept the answer as soon as I can :)